# sums of sections of array

Tags: ruby

I have an array `xs` of numbers and I need to calculate sums of elements in three consecutive sections in it. the sections are `xs[0]`, `xs[1, N]` and `xs[N + 1, N]` for some integer `N`. For example, for `N = 2`:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] #=> 1, 5, 9
```

my implementation is below. I could not make it more memory/speed efficient, but it still bothers me, I guess I have nothing else to do right now, but maybe there is a more elegant and succinct way to do this? I do not have to produce an array, it can be any other structure.

```
xs.each_with_index.reduce([0, 0, 0]) do |m, x|
  v, i = x
  j = (i > N ? 2
       : i > 0 ? 1
       : 0)
  m[j] += v.to_i
  m
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[xs[0..0],xs[1..N],xs[N+1..-1]].map{|x|x.reduce{|a,b|a+b}}
```

`a.rb`:

```
N = (rand * 1E6).to_i
xs = 1.upto(1E6).to_a

xs.each_with_index.reduce([0, 0, 0]) do |m, x|
  v, i = x
  j = (i > N ? 2
       : i > 0 ? 1
       : 0)
  m[j] += v.to_i
  m
end
```

`b.rb`:

```
N = (rand * 1E6).to_i
xs = 1.upto(1E6).to_a

[xs[0..0],xs[1..N],xs[N+1..-1]].map{|x|x.reduce{|a,b|a+b}}
```

Times:

```
$ time ruby a.rb 
ruby a.rb  0.85s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.860 total

$ time ruby b.rb 
ruby b.rb  0.29s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.296 total
```

Ruby version:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin12.0.0]
```

Comment: thanks. this creates additional objects in memory. i want to avoid this.

Comment: I've timed my implementation against yours and seems to be faster. weird

Comment: Slices of arrays are efficient - they don't actually entail copying the entire array

Answer (score 2):

Little variant:

```
[xs[0..0],xs[1..N],xs[N+1..-1]].map{|x|x.inject(:+)}
```